# Difference between Pressable and TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

With the update `react native` to version `0.63`, new components have appeared. Can someone more experienced explain how the `Pressable` differs from the `TouchableOpacity` and when it is better to use them.

Comment: You can read the Pressable [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/pressable#:~:text=Pressable%20is%20a%20Core%20Component,any%20of%20it's%20defined%20children.) to get a clear Idea.

Comment: Blog post with the announcement: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/07/06/version-0.63#pressable Note that it says *"We expect that most people will build and share components utilizing `Pressable` under the hood instead of relying on the default experience of something like `TouchableOpacity`."*

Comment: One thing that I do want to point out for future readers of this post - there is a slight timing difference between the `Pressable` component and `TouchableOpacity`. In a project that I'm working on that is very timing sensitive, `Pressable` has slightly more delay between the `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` events than `TouchableOpacity`. It's not enough to cause an issue in most cases, but if you do need something that is more performant, it is worthwhile to do some testing between the two yourself.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Pressable was a new introduction to RN 0.63, prior to that,Touchable Opacity was the most common used Component to wrap a  component or simliar components.

Both their basic functionalities are same, to make a text/image clickable and user interactive.

But with `Pressable` you get to access a lot new props like :

`HitRect`, which is such a cool feature, acc to docs :

> Fingers are not the most precise instruments, and it is common for
> users to accidentally activate the wrong element or miss the
> activation area. To help, `Pressable` has an optional `HitRect` you can
> use to define how far a touch can register away from the the wrapped
> element. Presses can start anywhere within a `HitRect`.

This is clearly a better alternative to what we used for `hitslop` , here its more precise and you define the area.And it doesnt interfere with the child/other components Z-index too.

So basically you get all the feature of a button, touchableOpacity with cool new props. Do check out thier docs : [rn-pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

***NOTE***: Also as other comments in this thread suggests, Pressable still doesnt have an   animation attached with the onPress Event

Hopeit helps.feel free for doubts

Comment: `Pressable` **doesn't add the opacity** animation on press, but react native docs have this note at touchableOpacity: "If you're looking for a more extensive and future-proof way to handle touch-based input, check out the Pressable API." so what's a future prrof way that also contains the auto opacity change?

Comment: You can change style of component in the "onPressIn" prop. @jave.web You can make opacity changes on onPressIn, and get back to normal opacity when onPressOut is clicked. It is customizable I think

Answer (score 36):

Just wanted to add a note about one drawback of `Pressable` and a workaround.

The drawback is `Pressable` has no automatic feedback like its TouchableOpacity counterpart.

However, you can add your own custom feedback with Pressable's `style` prop, which comes with a pressed state identifier:

```
<Pressable
  style={({ pressed }) => [
    { opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1.0 }
  ]}
  onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
>
 <View><Text>Press Me</Text></View>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: What you were trying to achieve, can b gotten using `android_ripple={{
        color: Colors.darkGray,
        borderless: false,
      }}` for Android.

Comment: touchable opacity is animated, this is not

Answer (score 16):

[image: Pressable] Here is a picture to clear your doubt.

How it works
On an element wrapped by

> Pressable

:

onPressIn is called when a press is activated.
onPressOut is called when the press gesture is deactivated.

After pressing onPressIn, one of two things will happen:

1. The person will remove their finger, triggering onPressOut followed by onPress.
2. If the person leaves their finger longer than 370 milliseconds before removing it, onLongPress is triggered. (onPressOut will still fire when they remove their finger.)

Please refer to [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/pressable) for more details.

Comment: Awesome, very clarifying! It will solve an issue I have, thanks!

Comment: Just an update, now the time seems to have changed from 370ms to 500ms. Not a game breaker change, but just interesting to point out!