# Detect scrolling when cells of a flat list are wrapped with button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have horizontal FlatList where every cell is wrapped by TouchableOpacity button (because I want to detect whether user has clicked on any cell).

However, this way, I can't scroll left-right, because every gesture is handled by parent button.

How can I pass the gesture event from the parent button to the child cell?

Below is an example of the implemented code:

```
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}
      onPress={previewMeasurement}
    >
      <Labels.Base
        textStyle={textStyles.measurementCellTime}
        text={item.datetime.time}
      />
      <TimePointer />
      <MeasurementList measurementValues={item.values} isLast={isLast} />
      {
        <AnimatedExpandCollapse
          onPress={shouldExpand}
          isExpanded={isExpanded}
          onEdit={onEdit}
          onDelete={onDelete}
          isLast={isLast}
        />
      }
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pressable` instead of `TouchableOpacity`. Both their basic functionalities are same, to make a text/image clickable and user interactive. You can find more details here [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810567/difference-between-pressable-and-touchableopacity) and [Link-2](https://medium.com/@mahyarmohammadi/react-native-pressable-vs-touchable-5fec6b332f15)

Comment: Pressable only offers us option to detect various stages of press interactions. I don't see how it can help me to pass the touch event through pressable to the cell when user is scrolling left or right?